# Pstricks bug: adding empty line messes pspicture

Tags: pstricks

I have the following Example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
    \newcommand{\directionFieldOneTangent}[2]{
       \pstVerb{%
          /aaaaaaaaa #1 \space def 
        }%
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red!60]( #1, #2){0.2}
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2.7,-2.7)(2.7,2.7)
    \directionFieldOneTangent{0}{0}

    \directionFieldOneTangent{0}{0}
    \end{pspicture}
    \end{document}
```

Now the same example, with one empty line removed:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
    \newcommand{\directionFieldOneTangent}[2]{
       \pstVerb{%
          /aaaaaaaaa #1 \space def 
        }%
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red!60]( #1, #2){0.2}
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-2.7,-2.7)(2.7,2.7)
    \directionFieldOneTangent{0}{0}
    \directionFieldOneTangent{0}{0}
    \end{pspicture}
    \end{document}
```

The first file produces the output in the first pdf file: the two points do not coincide. Where should I report this bug, how can that be fixed, what is the issue?

[image: Buggy image]

[image: Displays correctly]

Comment: It's not clear that it is necessarily a bug. A blank line is a `\par` command and the expected behaviour of `\par` is to inject vertical space. Perhaps a feature request that it be locally defined not to do that, but no package can make all incorrect input safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As far as I know, any blank lines in `pspicture` will be ignored.
2. Any trailing whitespace after the opening curly brace of `\newcommand{\<macroname>}` must be removed by using `%`.
3. Any trailing whitespace after the closing curly brace of `\pstVerb` must be removed by using `%`.

So there is no bug because they are all well-known facts.

```
\newcommand{\directionFieldOneTangent}[2]{%<============= You have to kill the whitespace!
   \pstVerb{%
      /aaaaaaaaa #1 \space def 
    }%
\pscircle*[linecolor=red!60]( #1, #2){0.2}
}
```

Comment: it wouldn't hurt to add a `%` after `0.2}` as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! That resolves the issue.  I follow all your % advice. As far as calling this behavior a bug... I like to stir up some controversy! When white space causes such drastic and difficult to predict changes, some controversial statements are deserved (If I were to design LaTeX/pstricks, I'd avoid such shady syntax behavior of the white space).